# iPhone Homescreen/Weather app question [relating to views & gesture recognition]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to implement the side swiping gesture to go from one objet to another. Just trying to figure out what its called so I can start looking up some tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Add your view controllers to [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and set the [`pagingEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled) property of the scroll view to *YES*.

The small dots displyed at the bottom of the iPhone's home screen is [`UIPageControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You need to configure it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UIScrollView to implement paging.